# Burnside's lemma adding constants $\pmod{10}.$

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, discrete-mathematics

> **Problem:** On how many ways can you color the numbers $0$ to $9$ with
>   two different colors (say red and blue) if the colorings are counted
>   as the same when they can be transferred to eachother by adding a
>   constant mod $10$?
>
> For example, a coloring where the numbers $2,4$ and $9$ are red is
>   counted as the same as the coloring where $5,7$ and $2$ are red since
>   the latter is obtained by adding 3 in mod $10$.

**My attempt:** So each addition of constant can be thought of rotating the ring $0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9$ once so that $0\rightarrow 1,1\rightarrow 2$, etc. So if we add the constant $5$ we get $0\rightarrow 5,1\rightarrow 6$ etc. Thus the group of symmetries is

$$G=\{0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9\}, \quad |G|=10.$$

Now we need to find the fixes of $g$ and compute

$$\frac{1}{|G|}\sum_{g\in G}\text{Fix}(g).$$

The identity does nothing, meaning that no matter how we colour these $10$ numbers, they are always fixed, thus there are $2^{10}$ fixes for this symmetry.

Adding $1$ changes all the colors of all the spots, the only way our settings are fixed is if we color all the numbers blue or all the numbers red, thus we have two different colorings giving $2^2$ fixes.

I'm stuck. I don't know how to think through this. I feel there should be some easier way.

Comment: Hint: you are along the right lines trying to understand $\mathrm{Fix}(g)$ for specific examples of $g$. You've done $g = 0$ and $g = 1$. What about $g = 2, 3, \ldots$?

Comment: @RobArthan - That's my problem somewhat. My brain can't deal with $g=2$. We get that $0\rightarrow 2, 1\rightarrow 3,...$ so every even number (including $0$) is mapped on the next even number and the same for odd. So if we color all the odd numbers one color and all the even numbers the other color we get $2^2$ fixes? Same goes then for $g=3$ and $g=4$.  But I feel like $g=5$ should be the same but it isn't.

Comment: A colouring is fixed by $2$ if you can obtain it by choosing a colouring for $0$ and $1$ (the members of a fundamental domain for the action of $2$) and then transferring it to the rest of $0, \ldots 9$ by translation.

Comment: @RobArthan - I think you have to elaborate on that one. What is fundamental domain?

Comment: For $g=2$, a coloring that alternates between blue and red is a fix.

Comment: @frabala - Yes, I think this is what I concluded in one of my previous comments.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are correct that $\def\fix{\operatorname{Fix}}\fix(0)=2^{10}$, while you should instead have $\fix(1)=2^1$. From your comments, you are correct that $\fix(2)=2^2$.

Consider $\fix(3)$. Once $0$ is colored, the chain $0\to 3\to 6\to 9\to 2\to 5\to 8\to 1\to 4\to 7$ implies that everything has the same color as $0$. Therefore, you only can freely choose one color, so $\fix(3)=2^1$.

For $\fix(4)$, we have the chains $0\to 4\to 8\to 2\to 6$ and $1\to 5\to 9\to 3\to 7$, so $\fix(4)=2^2$, as both chains can be colored freely.

For $\fix(5)$, there are five chains of two elements, each of the form $i\to (i+5)$ for $i=0,1,2,3,4$. Each chain can be colored freely, so $\fix(i)=2^5$.

Can you continue, computing $\fix(k)$ for $k=6,7,8,9$?

Comment: Following your wonderfuI method, I got that $\text{fix}(6)=2^2,\text{fix}(7)=2^1,\text{fix}(8)=2^2$ and $\text{fix}(9)=2^1.$ Adding all these upp and dividing by $10$ I got the correct answer $108.$ So I guess all the cycles, which are the exponents, are actually all the possible unique chains for each fix.